# how to hide "fab" button for a specific fragment activity?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

How do I hide "fab" button, when clicked or opened a specific fragment?

I want to hide From bellow fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View newExchange= inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_exchange,container,false);


        recyclerView=newExchange.findViewById(R.id.step1recycleView);
        datalist=new ArrayList<>();
        exchangeAdapter=new NewExchangeAdapter(datalist,getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(exchangeAdapter);
        loadData();

        FloatingActionButton fab =newExchange.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//this is generating error on setVisibility

        return newExchange;




    }
```

Here I set fab button on click

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                 //       .setAction("Action", null).show();

                fragment=new NewExchangeFrag();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
                fab.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);//This way also generating error on setVisibility
```

Also I tried to use `fab.hide();` and this is crashing my application

What is correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to access the fab but after you replaced the fragment. I don't understand why are are trying to hide the button after removing the fragment. The button doesn't exist anymore.

Try

`fab.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE)`

before

`fragment=new NewExchangeFrag()`.

In reality, you don't even need to hide the button.

Comment: Maybe my explanation problem, I used navigation drawer, on click fab button not opening a totally  new activity but replacing fragment and navigation header fab and navigation drawer still exist and I just want to remove fab button when replaced to newExchangeFrag()

Comment: so do fab.setVisibility(View.Invisible) inside the onCreatView() of the fragment where you don't want the button to be visible.

Comment: I did please take a look my first block of code and that falsifying error

Answer (score 0):

You should set visibility attribute for floating action button in xml file of NewExchangeFragment if You want it to be hidden when fragment is inflated.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

As for hiding button when it is clicked, You should call setVisibility method before inflating new Fragment

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fragment = new NewExchangeFrag();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```